# How to add data automatically in wordpress forms

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a wordpress site. In that i want to add data of 1000 employees. I have that data in a seaparate excel file. But in order to display data of each employee , i have to add his details in a form . The administrator made it in this way that for entering a new employee , select 'members' option in wordpress dashboard . From there fill the details of new employee in a form with fields like 'name' , 'phone no.' 'Address'.

I used csv exporter plugin. It can import csv documents in to wordpress database. But how to use this to display all data on my site?!

Comment: Could you please explain more what you trying to do?

Comment: Sir i have data in excel sheets. I want all that data to be displayed on my site automatically. Any plugin for that?

Comment: You could add them as users with the details as user metadata. To import the users data from the excel file you could use http://www.wpallimport.com/